# T3PO3 v10: How to use RouteEnhancer with ArrayPaginator?

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-10.x, typo3-11.x

I'm using the `ArrayPaginator` for my Extbase list view, since Fluid widget functionality will no longer be available in TYPO3 v11.

And I'm currently trying to use the RouteEnhancer with this.

My list action just receives the argument for the current page as integer.

And the code for the RouteEnhancer looks like this:

```
  RefList:
    type: Extbase
    limitToPages:
      - 142
    extension: Ref
    plugin: Pi2
    routes:
      -
        routePath: /seite-{page}
        _controller: 'Ref::list'
        _arguments:
          page: currentPage
    defaultController: 'Ref::list'
    requirements:
      page: \d+
    aspects:
      page:
        type: StaticRangeMapper
        start: '1'
        end: '1000'
```

I've seen a lot examples for the Fluid pagination widget that contained the value `@widget_0/currentPage` for the argument `page`.

The URL is generated correctly if I switch to another page but the content displayed from the list view is still the same as on page 1.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can us a QueryResultPaginator instead of a ArrayPaginator.

**Route**

```
routeEnhancers:
  RefList:
    type: Extbase
    extension: Ref
    plugin: Pi2
    routes:
      - routePath: '/'
        _controller: 'Ref::list'
      - routePath: '/{page}'
        _controller: 'Ref::list'
        _arguments:
          page: current-page
    defaultController: 'Ref::list'
    aspects:
      current-page:
        type: StaticRangeMapper
        start: '1'
        end: '100'
```

**RefController.php** Get current-page from request

```
public function listAction()
{
    $refs = $this->refRepository->findAll();

    $currentPage = $this->request->hasArgument('current-page') ? $this->request->getArgument('current-page') : 1;
    $paginatedRefs = new QueryResultPaginator($refs, $currentPage, $this->itemsPerPage);
    $simplePagination = new SimplePagination($paginatedRefs);
    $pagination = $this->buildSimplePagination($simplePagination, $paginatedRefs);

    $this->view->assignMultiple([
        'refs' => $paginatedRefs,
        'pagination' => $pagination,
    ]);
}


/**
 * Build simple pagination
 *
 * @param SimplePagination $simplePagination
 * @param QueryResultPaginator $paginator
 * @return array
 */
protected function buildSimplePagination(SimplePagination $simplePagination, QueryResultPaginator $paginator): array
{
    $firstPage = $simplePagination->getFirstPageNumber();
    $lastPage = $simplePagination->getLastPageNumber();
    return [
        'lastPageNumber' => $lastPage,
        'firstPageNumber' => $firstPage,
        'nextPageNumber' => $simplePagination->getNextPageNumber(),
        'previousPageNumber' => $simplePagination->getPreviousPageNumber(),
        'startRecordNumber' => $simplePagination->getStartRecordNumber(),
        'endRecordNumber' => $simplePagination->getEndRecordNumber(),
        'currentPageNumber' => $paginator->getCurrentPageNumber(),
        'pages' => range($firstPage, $lastPage)
    ];
}
```

**List.html** add pagination template

```
<f:for each="{refs.paginatedItems}" as="ref">
    <f:render partial="List/ListItem" arguments="{ref: ref}" />
</f:for>
<f:render partial="List/Pagination" arguments="{pagination:pagination, action:'list'}" />
```

**Partial List/Pagination.html**

add links for pagination: previous

```
<f:link.action action="{action}" arguments="{current-page:pagination.previousPageNumber}">previous</f:link.action>
```

add links for pagination: pages

```
<f:link.action action="{action}" arguments="{current-page:page}">{page}</f:link.action>
```

add links for pagination: next

```
<f:link.action action="{action}" arguments="{current-page: pagination.nextPageNumber}">next</f:link.action>
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. But isn't this essentialy the same solution that I posted in my answer? I mean getting the current page from the request params.

Comment: You're right - it is essentialy the same solution. Just more complete and more the TYPO3 way I think.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround.
Inside the controller list action:  `$currentPage = (int) ($_GET['tx_ref_pi2']['currentPage'] ?? 1);`